# Linebreak in cventry

Tags: moderncv

I am using the latex style moderncv with command `\cventry` which has the definition as follows:

```
% makes a typical resume job / education entry
% usage: \cventry[spacing]{years}{degree/job title}{institution/employer}{localization}{optionnal: grade/...}{optional: comment/job description}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{}
```

I am using this to create a CV entry for my current employment however, my institution/employer entry is too long to fit  on one line and I get an overfull hbox. How can I wrap this onto the next line?

A MWE is given below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}       
\moderncvstyle{banking}                           
\moderncvcolor{blue}                              
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     
\usepackage[scale=0.82]{geometry}
\usepackage{import}
\name{Joe}{Bloggs}
\address{Somewhere Street, Somewhere}{12345}{Country}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Current Employment}

\vspace{6pt}

\begin{itemize}

\item{\cventry{date--present}{Job Title}{Job name}{Long name of my current employer which causes an overfull hbox and runs off the edge of the page}{}{}{\vspace{3pt}}}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The output is shown below:

[image: Overflowing Hbox]

Ideally I would like to wrap the overflowing Hbox onto a new line (still right aligned so that 'Long name of my current employer...' doesn't collide with the left-handside Hbox ('Job title') and run off the right-hand side margin. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Actually, the definition of `\cventry`  that your MWE uses is the following: `\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\maincolumnwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
    {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5}\\%
    {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
  \else{\\%
    \begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}%
      \small#7%
    \end{minipage}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}` (taken from `moderncvbodyiii.sty` that is loaded by the `banking` style of `moderncv`.)

Answer (score 2):

The current definition of command `\cventry` does not allow to get what you want. But you can define an new command `\mycventry` like this:

```
\newcommand*{\mycventry}[8][.25em]{ % <=================================
  \begin{tabular*}{\maincolumnwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}% 
  {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5}\\% 
   & {\bfseries #8} \\ % <==============================================
  {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\% 
  \end{tabular*}% 
  \ifx&#7&% 
  \else{\\% 
  \begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}% 
    \small#7% 
  \end{minipage}}\fi% 
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

As you can see I added an 8th parameter (`#8`) to take the second part of your needed text. So parameter 5 (`#5`) takes the first part of your text, parameter 8 the second part. If you want you can change the used parameters to get both text parts in for example parameter 5 and 6, but then you have to change the new command `\mycventry`. Your case is very special, I think the given solution above is good enouph ...  You can use is like this:

```
\item \mycventry{date--present--2}%
  {Job Title--3}%
  {Job name--4}%
  {Long name of my current employer whichcauses an--5}%
  {--6}%
  {--7}%
  { overfull hbox and runs off the edge of the page--8}% <=========================
```

With the following complete code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.82]{geometry}
\usepackage{import}

\name{Joe}{Bloggs}
\address{Somewhere Street, Somewhere}{12345}{Country}

\newcommand*{\mycventry}[8][.25em]{ % <=================================
  \begin{tabular*}{\maincolumnwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}% 
  {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5}\\% 
   & {\bfseries #8} \\ % <==============================================
  {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\% 
  \end{tabular*}% 
  \ifx&#7&% 
  \else{\\% 
  \begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}% 
    \small#7% 
  \end{minipage}}\fi% 
  \par\addvspace{#1}}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Current Employment}

\vspace{6pt}

\begin{itemize}

%\item \cventry{date--present--2}{Job Title--3}{Job name--4}{Long name of my current employer whichcauses an overfull hbox \\ and runs off the edge of the page--5}{--6}{--7}%{\vspace{3pt}}

\item \mycventry{date--present--2}{Job Title--3}{Job name--4}{Long name of my current employer whichcauses an--5}{--6}{--7}{ overfull hbox and runs off the edge of the page--8}% <=========================

\item \cventry{year--year--2}{Degree--3}{Institution--4}{City--5}{\textit{Grade}--6}{Description--7}  % arguments 4 to 7 can be left empty

\item \cventry{year--year--2}{Degree--3}{}{}{}{}  % arguments 4 to 7 can be left empty

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

you get the following resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]